# Understanding SMP concept in linux

Tags: linux, unix, smp

Recently i have started getting into SMP programming, was trying to understand the concepts and experiment examples in Linux. When i started around Googling for the same, i came across the below book:

UNIX Systems for Modern Architectures: Symmetric Multiprocessing and Caching for Kernel 
Programmers

This books is really good and delivers what i says but i am confused or not clear, if the same concepts applies to Linux also: For eg: virtual cache, do they exist for Linux...

Basically i am seeking advice as to how much this book would be helpful if i am purely working in Linux only environment.

Comment: According to the reviews it covers a number of CPU architectures, although many of those (e.g. 68040) are somewhat out of date.  I doubt it has much that is specific to any one flavour of Unix, so the theory in the book is probably applicable to Linux.  What it won't have is any guide to the Linux kernel itself.  However, there are other books on that subject.

Comment: Thanks. What is the good/best book for understanding linux internals? I have checked Orielly, anything else?

Comment: Not sure.  The O'Reilly book was OK in its day but I haven't done anything inside a kernel since about 1997.  However, there are truckloads of resources on the web.

Answer (score 2):

Read more about [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/), [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) & [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [Remote Procedure Calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call), [Message Passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing), [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) and [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html), [semaphores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) and [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html), [event loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) and [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) with the [C10K problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem), [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface), [JSON-RPC](http://json-rpc.org/), etc...

Of course I am assuming you want to program user-land applications (not kernel modules).

Comment: Thanks... was greedy if i could find a single book :)